# Autofilter, copy and the insert. Data isn't insert even though the code runs without errors

Tags: excel, vba

Below code runs "perfectly". I can see that the data is filtered, and I can see that the correct range is selected. And I'm assuming that the data in the range is copied.

However, when trying to insert the copied data, nothing appears. I can see that there is data in the range which is supposedly copied.

The weird thing is that I know it worked at some point, and suddenly it didn't.

```
Const sFILE_PATH    As String = "C:\Downloads\"
Const sEXTENSION    As String = ".xlsm"

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow_Offset As Long

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sFileName As String

sFileName = "2018"

Set wbk = Workbooks(sFileName & sEXTENSION)


lastrow_Offset = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow = wbk.Sheets("Acc").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False




With wbk.Sheets("Acc")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A4:AL" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:="=NC", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Range("A4:AL" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:="=New", Operator:=xlFilterValues



     Debug.Print Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address

    .Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy



    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("H26").Offset((lastrow_Offset + 1) - 26, 0).Insert

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: If I sort the data before running the code, so all the rows with the right criteria is in the top (it's about 5 lines), then the data I copied correct.

Comment: What happens if you move the line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("H26").Offset((lastrow_Offset + 1) - 26, 0).Insert` before `.AutoFilterMode = False`

Comment: Doens't work. The data is still not copied, and inserted.

Comment: `Debug.Print Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address` gives you the correct address?

Comment: Also check what is the value of `lastrow`

Comment: Have you stepped through to see what's going on? What happens if you paste rather than Insert?

Comment: Debug gives me $C$5:$C$252 which is the entire Column with data in it. And yes I have tried taking it step-by-step. And the data is filtered correctly and all.

Comment: So when I use PasteSpecial it works. How can that be?

Comment: Can you try this for me? Replace `.Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` with `Dim Rng as Range: Set Rng = .Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` And just before `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("H26").Offset((lastrow_Offset + 1) - 26, 0).Insert`, type this `Rng.Copy: DoEvents` What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You don't paste your data. The `Insert`-command simply creates a new (empty) line, that's all.

Change your code to

```
With wbk.Sheets(1)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A4:AL" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:="=NC", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Range("A4:AL" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:="=New", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    lastrow_Offset = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row
    Dim destCell As Range
    Set destCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("H26").Offset((lastrow_Offset + 1) - 26, 0)
    .Range("C1:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destCell

    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

**Update**: as Siddharth Rout pointed out, I was wrong, the `Insert` pastes data. However, it seems that this is not working if a non-contiguous range was selected for copy - as it is the most cases for filtered data.

In that case, either provide the destination-parameter already when copying the data (as I do in my code above) or use the `PasteSpecial`-method of the destination range. I prefer to use the first method as it doesn't keep the data in the paste-buffer, but that's a minor thing.

Comment: `You don't paste your data. The Insert-command simply creates a new (empty) line, that's all.` That is not true. If you copy the data, you can use `.Insert` to paste the copied cells :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Hmm, you're right - but somehow it's not working when I make the `Copy` (without destination) and use `dest.Insert` afterwards. I will investigate...

Comment: Well then I should have been able to use Insert.  I just changed the insert to PasteSpecial.

Comment: `it seems that this is not working if a non-contiguous range was selected for copy` True but I crossed checked before. it is contiguous. See my 2nd comment and the reply to that in the comment section below the question

Comment: My question was `Debug.Print Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address gives you the correct address? – Siddharth Rout` and Stefan's answer was `Debug gives me $C$5:$C$252 which is the entire Column with data in it. And yes I have tried taking it step-by-step. And the data is filtered correctly and all. – Stefan 1 hour ago `

Comment: Yes, I know - but my experiments showed me that as long as the range is contiguous, `Insert` copies the data, but if it is not, it doesn't.

Comment: Yup I agree with you :)